# Searching for bad Minecraft questions on Gaming.SE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stackexchange, t-sql

To preface this post a little bit, I'll explain a little bit of the *"backstory"* here. The Stack Exchange site, [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), also known as Arqade, often has a large influx of bad questions about the popular video game, [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net). Many of these questions are either easy to find on a search engine, horribly unclear, have been asked before, are treating Arqade like a forum, or are asking for things like account support, which only the company that produces the game can provide. A few examples might include:

> 1. [what is the best biome to spawn in minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238828/what-is-the-best-biome-to-spawn-in-minecraft)
> 2. [Can't Log In To Minecraft Account After 1.9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239003/cant-log-in-to-minecraft-account-after-1-9)
> 3. [No .Minecraft folder at school](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190923/no-minecraft-folder-at-school)
> 4. [What I need to make TNT?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137288/what-i-need-to-make-tnt)
> 5. [How to Spawn Herobrine without Mods?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132807)

The query essentially searches in a manner like this:

- It looks for questions with tags that are like `%minecraft%` or `%minecraft-%%`.
- It checks to see if it has a score *below* -1.
- It checks to make sure that the post hasn't already been deleted.
- It checks to see if it's either been closed, or not closed.

I'd like to know the following things:

- Is there a way to make this shorter and less repetitive?
- Are there any redundant checks that aren't needed?
- Are there any checks that could cause problems?
- Anything else?

Here's the code, and the [query link](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/374932/shtty-minecraft-questions-that-have-been-left-undeleted-or-unacted-upon):

```
SELECT
    Id AS [Post Link]
  , OwnerUserId AS [User Link]
  , Score
FROM Posts WHERE
  DeletionDate IS NULL
  AND Score <= -1
  AND (
    Tags LIKE '%minecraft-%%'
    OR Tags LIKE '%minecraft%'
  )
  AND (
    ClosedDate IS NULL 
    OR ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
  );


SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM Posts WHERE
  DeletionDate IS NULL
  AND Score <= -1
  AND (
    Tags LIKE '%minecraft-%%'
    OR Tags LIKE '%minecraft%'
  )
  AND (
    ClosedDate IS NULL 
    OR ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
  );
```

Comment: Aside: [[minecraft] score:..-1 is:question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bminecraft%5D+score%3A..-1+is%3Aquestion) in search does much the same thing.  You *might* also want to display the size (as a small size often correlates with a poor question).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The use of the Tags field on the Post is a poor choice for the query. It relies on a table scan, which is slow, because it has to check each question. Note, you can use the `<` and `>` characters to identify tag start and end values in the Tags column, but, as I say, don't use that column.

Instead, you should do a join with the `PostTags` and `Tags` tables. Using a CTE to simplify that query makes sense.

I really dislike the all-caps style of SQL, but realize that there is no standard. If you can change standards, please use lower-case for keywords... it makes the column and table names much easier to see (and those are the important parts). Still, you get +1 for being consistent in your capitalization. Consistency is really important, and you nailed it.

Note that the `Posts` table has no deleted posts, none. There's no need to check the `DeletedDate` at all.

So, joining Tags to PostTags gets you minecraft-tagged posts. Joining that to Posts gets you the ones you can test scores and closures on.

Here are [unclosed, low-scoring, minecraft-related posts....](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/374936/shtty-minecraft-questions-that-have-been-left-undeleted-or-unacted-upon):

```
WITH mctags AS (
  SELECT Id AS tid
  FROM Tags
  WHERE TagName LIKE 'minecraft%'
), mcqs AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT PostId
  FROM PostTags INNER JOIN mctags ON TagId = tid
)
SELECT
    Id AS [Post Link],
    OwnerUserId AS [User Link],
    Tags,
    Score
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN mcqs ON Id = PostId
WHERE Score <= -1
  AND ClosedDate IS NULL
  AND PostTypeId = 1
```

Note, I have tried to continue using your all-caps keywords.... despite myself ;-)

Hmmm, some aditional notes:

- your text says you check for questions "below -1", but your code checks for questions "below 0" ... there is a difference between `<` and `<=`.
- it does not check the closed-status of the post. If you want to see if a currently-open post was closed in the past, you need to check the `PostHistory` table.

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't do anything at all.

> ```
> ClosedDate IS NULL 
> OR ClosedDate IS NOT NULL
> ```

Saying "where is or not" results in the same thing as not including the statement at all. Either you're not getting the right results, or this could be removed.